# Problem understanding a django form

Tags: django

```
class UserField(forms.EmailField):
def clean(self, value):
    super(UserField, self).clean(value)
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=value)
        raise forms.ValidationError("There is an existing account associated with this email.")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return value
```

the try except method is straightforward. However, I am having a hard time figuring out the

```
super(UserField, self).clean(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super(UserField, self).clean(value)` is calling the ancestor method : `forms.EmailField.clean(value)` to check that the email is well formed.